# Changing the current direction arrow in TikZ' circuits.ee library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, circuits, tikz-shape, tikz-circuit-lib

I want to change the arrow tip used for indicating the current directions in Ti*k*Z' `circuits.ee` library (first path in the MWE below) to something else, say the `Stealth` tip (second path in the MWE). In section 49.4.9 of the manual (*Implementation: The EE-Symbols Shape Library*) it says about `direcion ee`

> This shape is rather special. It is intended to be used to “turn an arrow tip into a shape”.

It then goes on to explain how the height of the arrow tip is calculated in an unusual manner.

The sentence above suggests that I can use this key to turn any other arrow tip (like `Stealth`) into a shape that can then be used for `current direction` and `direction info`. However, it is totally unclear to me how to do this. Maybe I misunderstood the intent of the key.

How can I replace the shape to indicate currents by `circuits.ee`? Ideally this should not affect the arrow tip used by the other annotations.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [circuit ee IEC]
  \draw (0,0)
    to[current source={direction info={info={\(I\)}}}] ++(2, 0)
    to[current direction] ++(2,0);
  \draw [->, >={Stealth[scale=.8]}] (0.7,-1) to ++(.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]